# How exactly does the Endless Bonus mechanic work?

Tags: warframe

In endless void fissure missions, you get a bonus reward every time you open a relic. At least that's what people have told me. I'm not sure if this is true for the following two reasons:

1) The [wiki about this subject](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Void_Fissure#Endless_Missions) reads:

> Should you collect the necessary Reactant per interval and open your
>   Relic, a bonus will occur and you will be allowed to re-select a new
>   Relic for the next interval.

This sounds like you only get the bonus if you choose to stay and play another round (or interval).

2) After the fifth interval, you supposedly get a void relic. However, this relic doesn't show up in the mission rewards like the other relics you've obtained do.

---

So when do we really get these rewards? Do we get the first booster after round 1 or after round 2? Do we get the first relic after round 5 or after round 6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the wiki:

> Every time you open a Relic, you get a predetermined booster. These boosters stack the longer you stay.
>
> - The first interval: 1.25x Affinity.
> - The second interval: 1.25x Credits.
> - The third interval: 1.25x Resources.
> - The fourth interval: 1.25x Resource Drop Rate.
> - The fifth interval: a random Exceptional Relic (that can be used in the same mission).
> - The sixth interval: 1.5x Affinity (replaces first).
> - The seventh interval: 1.5x Credits (replaces second).
> - The eighth interval: 1.5x Resources (replaces third).
> - The ninth interval: 1.5x Resource Drop Rate (replaces fourth).
> - The tenth interval: a higher tier random Flawless Relic (that can be used in the same mission).
> - Boosters continue to increase every set of intervals and are capped at double (2x). After the nineteenth interval, all boosters reached their cap.

After the first "round", you get the first interval bonus.   Same goes for all other bonuses.  The relic that drops is directly sent to your inventory, allowing you to immediately use said relic during the next round's relic pick.   It is not an end-of-mission reward, as the wiki clearly states that it can be used in the same mission, and it is for that reason you will not see it in the mission reward list.

Comment: So since the relics are dropped directly into your inventory, that means you get to keep them even if you fail the mission? That's interesting.

Comment: Yes, it is indeed interesting and quite fortunate that we use up the relics only when it's confirmed that we got something from them :)